# Running ProtonVPN on login through /etc/profile.d

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, script

I have a simple script to run my VPN on login. The script is located in

*/etc/profile.d/connectVPN.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
protonvpn c -f > /home/myUserName/Desktop/out.txt
```

The contents of the output file:

```
[!] The program was not executed as root.
[!] Please run as root.
```

*ls -l /etc/profile.d/connectVPN.sh*

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 59 Dec 23 15:22 /etc/profile.d/connectVPN.sh
```

The VPN does not start since the script is not being run as root. How do I fix this?

*ls -lF /home/MyUserName/Desktop/out.txt*

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 measure measure 74 Dec 29 22:27 Desktop/out.txt
```

Comment: is the `protonvpn` file a shell script or a binary? If it's the latter, you could do this with a suid bit - this can be determined by looking at the output of`file $(which protonvpn)`.

 If it's a binary, try running this command: `chmod u+s $(which protonvpn)`. This will make it so anyone who executes `protonvpn` does so with root privileges (this is a security risk depending on exactly what that command is capable of doing, so proceed with caution). Also for this to work the root user will have to own the file, which can be done with `ls -l $(which protonvpn)`.

Comment: I tried both of these as well as other methods that I have researched to no success. I am not sure what constitutes as binary, but protonvpn is a `setuid Python script, ASCII text executable, although I did just change the suid.

Comment: Please append output of ```ls -lF /home/myUserName/Desktop/out.txt``` to your question.

Comment: @dirdi I added it the main post.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use sudo passwordless for the proton command for the user you want to run the VPN;

by editing the /etc/sudoers.d/ folder add a file (any name is fine, like proton) with the following entry (assuming username is: **measure** and path of protonvpn is **/bin/protonvpn**):

```
measure NOPASSWD: /bin/protonvpn
```

> **NOTE:** modify the executable path and/or username if is not correct

then modify */etc/profile.d/connectVPN.sh* from:

```
#!/bin/bash
protonvpn c -f > /home/myUserName/Desktop/out.txt
```

to:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /bin/protonvpn c -f > /home/myUserName/Desktop/out.txt
```

and try it again.

Personally, if is not a problem the VPN start at system boot, I'm suggesting you to manage it with systemd.

---

**EDIT**
Below and example how to manage a script with systemd once  a network is connected:

```
[Unit]
Description=Protonvpn

[Service]
Type=idle
# as root the sudo command can be removed.
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo /bin/protonvpn c -f > /home/myUserName/Desktop/out.txt
# with the following user and group you need the sudoers.d file
# if you want to run it as root user change user and group with root
User=measure
Group=measure
Restart=always
RestartSec=30

[Install]
# this make the trick, script will be executed only once the 
# connection to a network has been established
WantedBy=network-online.target
```

> Source: [This blog post for the systemd script](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=207103)

save the previously code in a file under: */etc/systemd/system/* and make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/systemd/system/protonvpn.service
```

reload the systemd to discover new service:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Enable the service to start at the boot time:

```
sudo systemctl enable protonvpn
```

Test it with:

```
sudo systemctl start protonvpn
```

and for the last check verify the service start the VPN normally also @reboot